# directory_iterator skip over inaccessible files folders Windows

Tags: c++, windows, c++17

I am trying to iterate over all the folders in my `C:\` directory, and ONLY in the C:\ directory. Not in any subfolders. My current problem is that it includes inaccessible files and folders like `swapfile.sys` or `System Volume Information` when iterating. How can I check the flags or whatnot to exclude such objects?

```
for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir))    
{
    
    // Have the if() check here to see if it's accessible
        directory.emplace_back(f);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`fs::status(entry).permissions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/status) to get the permissions of the current entry and choose whether to skip it according to its [flag value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/perms).

```
for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(dir)) {
  auto p = fs::status(entry).permissions();
  if ((p & fs::perms::owner_read) != fs::perms::none)
    directory.emplace_back(f);
}
```

Comment: Why not use [`entry.status()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/status) instead of `fs::status(entry)`?

Comment: I used a try/catch around `auto p = fs::status(entry).permissions();` to skip over the files like `swapfile.sys`, since that will crash on those. The current problem though is your code does not prevent objects like `System Volume Information` or `Documents and Settings`. This is due to the fact that the code you posted shows that it has `All` permissions despite being inaccessible. There must be some way to prevent it..

Comment: @MemeMachine "*I used a try/catch ... to skip over [inaccessible] files ... since that will crash on those*" - `status()` has a non-throwing overload that can return a [`std::error_code`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code) instead, which will give you access to the underlying OS error code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I'll check that momentarily. I just noticed there is a `_Is_symlink_or_junction()` function. It filters out Documents and Settings, but not System Volume Information. I'll continue searching for solutions

Comment: I just need a way to check the _`Attributes` to see if it has the System flag. Let me know if you have any ideas. https://imgur.com/a/XjbdOxI < I need a way to check if that flag is there

Comment: @MemeMachine The `<filesystem>` library does not expose access to that kind of information. You will have to use the Win32 API [`GetFileAttributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesw) function instead, checking the result for the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM` flag.

Answer (score 0):

If the iteration is failing due to trying to access an inaccessible item, you can specify the `skip_permission_denied` flag in the iterator's constructor, eg:

```
for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir, std::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied))    
{
    directory.emplace_back(f);
}
```

Comment: I knew of this. The issue is that the iteration is not failing.

Comment: @MemeMachine well, you didn't make that clear enough in your question.

Comment: No worries, I should have specified.

Comment: @MemeMachine I have your same identical problem! Did you find a solution in the end ?